# List component using RXJS Angular

Tags: typescript, pagination, angular-2+, rxjs

I have a small angular project, where I have an Article component to list articles with pagination system.

1. The default page[image]
2. The placeholder loader page[image]

The main objectives are:

- Display the articles after consuming a GET API ressource.
- Paginating the articles with [ngb-pagination](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples).
- Display a placeholder loader in case the response is not ready yet.

My code works perfectly, except that I notice a little refresh of the page each time I paginate to another page. I'm sure that my code need a lot of improvements.

I'm gonna show you my code, and I ask you to help me to improve it. (you can find [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ahmed-bhs/angular6-demo/tree/74157f865af32ff5d916027e6db2e26e22276b00).

This my `article.compononent.ts`

```
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  itemsPerPage: any;
  totalItems: any;
  page: any;
  previousPage: any;

  public observable$: Observable<any>;
  private _articlesUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}` + '/articles';
  public articles: any;
  readonly imagePath = `${environment.apiUrl}` + '/..';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.observable$ = this.http.get(this._articlesUrl).pipe(map((res: Response) => {

      this.page = res['page'];
      this.totalItems = res['total'];
      this.itemsPerPage = res['limit'];
      return res['_embedded']['items'];
    }));
    this.observable$.subscribe(
      (res) => this.articles = res
    );
  }

  loadPage(page: number) {
    if (page !== this.previousPage) {
      this.previousPage = page;
      this.loadData();
    }
  }

  loadData() {
     this.http.get(this._articlesUrl, {
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set('page', this.page)
        .set('per_page', this.itemsPerPage)
    }).pipe(map((res) => res['_embedded']['items'])).subscribe(
       (res: any[]) => this.articles = res
    );
  }

  trackElement(index: number, element: any) {
    return element ? element.id : null;
  }

  createRange(len= 20) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

This is the `article.component.html`

```
 <div class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="articles">
  <div class="blog-grids">
    <div class="grid" *ngFor="let article of (articles); trackBy: trackElement">
      <div class="entry-media" >
        <img [src]="imagePath + article.image" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="entry-body">
        <span class="cat">{{article.title}}</span>
        <h3><a [routerLink]="['/article/', article.id]">Visit {{article.title}}</a></h3>
        <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut..</p>
        <div class="read-more-date">
          <a href="#">Read More..</a>
          <span class="date">3 Hours ago</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="totalItems" [pageSize]="itemsPerPage" [(page)]="page" [maxSize]="2" [rotate]="true" (pageChange)="loadPage($event)"></ngb-pagination>
</div>

<masonry class="row mt-5" *ngIf="!(observable$ | async)">
  <masonry-brick class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let item of createRange(6)">
    <div class="timeline-item">
      <div class="animated-background">
        <div class="background-masker image"></div>
        <div class="background-masker header-bottom"></div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </masonry-brick>
</masonry>
```

Any code review, improvement, refactoring, recommendation, advices, pull-request would be appreciated and **voted**.

**EDIT**
This is what my api return as a result:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "categoryLabel": "category_label",
                "id": 275,
                "title": "Miss",
                "image": "/images/articles/9f9d5128ba85f715d5bf0c72d9609b89.jpg"
            },
            {
                "categoryLabel": "category_label",
                "id": 276,
                "title": "Dr.",
                "image": "/images/articles/79f58611ecfe946bc41a5aba403c2c3c.jpg"
            },
            {
                "categoryLabel": "category_label",
                "id": 277,
                "title": "Mr.",
                "image": "/images/articles/920574ee7bcf374e2b68eb7d698a64a4.jpg"
            },
            {
                "categoryLabel": "category_label",
                "id": 278,
                "title": "Prof.",
                "image": "/images/articles/b5d6da63fa2db61ac4e4e8ca01568a0d.jpg"
            },
            {
                "categoryLabel": "category_label",
                "id": 279,
                "title": "Prof.",
                "image": "/images/articles/940d7dcbd80f8ff8f3fd707bd92f681d.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    "route": "api_get_articles",
    "parameters": [],
    "absolute": false,
    "limit": 5,
    "total": 250,
    "limitparametername": "per_page",
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 50,
    "pageparametername": "page",
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! After getting an answer you should not change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. I've rolled back to revision 5.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the request made in `ngOnInit` seemed unclear to me. 
I presume if any pagination info is not provided, then the result contains the default pagination values such as `page`, `total`, `limit` or does it return all items?

Just in case, it is good practice to provide explicit default values such as `page: 0`, `limit: 20`etc. After setting the default values, `ngOnInit`should use `loadData` to fetch the items.

<strike>As far as i see, `observable$` variable is not used anywhere except `ngOnInit`, so i would remove it.</strike>

For fetching data or another possible operations on item(s) such as update, fetch, delete etc, i would create a `ItemService`. You can prefer it to be inject to your component.

Since typescript is a typed language i would define types for response and item.
Such as

```
interface Item {

}

interface ItemResponse {
    page: number;
    total: number;
    limit: number;
    items: Item[];
}
```

So from `ItemService` you may return observable of the proper type.

Edit: updated comment about `observable$` variable.